# Sort email address using compareTo() returns unexpected result

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm, sorting

I'm newbie to Java and trying to sort email address alphabetically using `compareTo()` but the result is not as I expect. I put my question in the code, could you please advise?

```
public class SortTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text1= "customer1@example.com";
        String text2 = "customer10@example.com";
        System.out.println(text1.compareTo(text2)); //Result is 16. Why? I expect a negative number as result.

        String text3= "customer1";
        String text4 = "customer10";
        System.out.println(text3.compareTo(text4)); //result is -1 which is correct.        
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:** 
I want to sort ascending with text1 and text2 above, the expected result in order is `"customer1@example.com"`, then `"customer10@example.com"`. Could u advise how to achieve it?

Comment: `'@'` is `64`, `'0'` is `48`. So `'@' > '0'`, meaning that `"customer1@".compareTo("customer10") > 0`. What's unexpected?

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand why it returns 16. I want to sort ascending with text1 and text2 above, the expected result in order is customer1@example.com, then customer10@example.com. Could u advise how to achive it?

Comment: Then it seems you need to compare the texts until `@`, something like `text1.substring(0, text1.indexOf("@")).compareTo(text2.substring(0, text2.indexOf("@")))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)):

> If there is no index position at which they differ, then the shorter string lexicographically precedes the longer string. In this case, compareTo returns the difference of the lengths of the strings -- that is, the value

This explains the second example.

In the first one "0" is lexicographically before "@". You can simply check that by running:

```
"@".compareTo("0")
```

which results in the value `16`.

Or another way:

```
(int) '@' // 64
(int) '0' // 48
```

So the difference is 16.

Edit: to compare the emails the way you want it, you should involve some more logic, for example compare only login part (remove the domain separated by `"@"`): `str1.split("@")[0].compareTo(str2.split("@")[0])`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the Ascii table - http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

'@' Dec value is 64
While '0' dec value is 48.

Now if you do (64-48) = 16.